# Generated Librariers create a Tsconfig.lib.json file with a comment that provides a Parsing Error for the compiler

Tags: angular, typescript, vscode-extensions

Im trying to figure out a work around for a compiler issue im having with a custom VS code extension im developing that generates minor angular applications.

The issue is when I generate components/lib from the templated files

It generates a tsconfig.lib.json/tsconfig.lib.prod.json/tsconfig.spec.json

Now the issue comes in when I try to compile these applications they have a parsing issue:

```
Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
 at new MetadataBuilder (*places*\meta-data.compiler.js:15:31)
    at extractPluginMetaData (*places*\builder.js:119:30)
    at *places*\builder.js:158:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (*places*node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:164:62)
```

The error is caused by the:

tsconfig.lib.json containing this comment:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */ <--- 
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Now I cant quite figure out how to bypass or supress this as its generated by the angular cli and I dont have enough control nor does angular provide options to remove those comments.

Any thoughts or ideas on how I can either Bypass/Remove or Supress the error

Notes on what i've tried:

Taking every TsConfig in the main Repo for the Extension and adding the compileroption to '      "removeComments": true,`